# Google doesn't list the links to my website

Tags: seo, pagerank, google-search-console

It is more than a month that there are 24+ links listed on my Google Webmasters account. However, when  **google** `link:m.a.sharpasand.com` none of them appears. Also, my page rank is **zero**.

I have tried different variations of `www.` and with out using `www.` but it doesn't work.

My website is on a subdomain but I don't think that it is a factor because I have forwarded the main domain with moved permanently. Its address is: [m.a.sharpasand.com](http://m.a.sharpasand.com/)

Thank you all so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everybody for your helps, but I got the answer from [webmasters.stackexchange.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

It seems that the Google link command is not accurate and the number in my webmasters account is important. There is a useful [article here](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/google-link-command-busting-the-myths).

The question in webmasters forum: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47380/google-doesnt-list-the-links-to-my-website

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did for my website:

1. Authenticate the website on Google's webmaster tools (www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) to certify that I am the owner of the website (they generate a file that you have to upload on your domain)
2. Generate a XML sitemap through one of the several free sitemap generators available on-line (they can be found using Google)
3. Upload the XML sitemap using Google's webmasters tools

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I've already done all of them and it is more than 3 months since that. But as I said in webmasters I can find my links which are more than 30 currently but not in Google itself using `link:`. Also, my page rank is still 0.